# In XML, what are the nodes with question marks called, and how do I add them in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

Here's an example of an XML file created in InfoPath:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <?mso-infoPathSolution solutionVersion="1.0.0.1" productVersion="12.0.0" PIVersion="1.0.0.0" href="file:///C:\Metastorm\Sample%20Procedures\InfoPath%20samples\Template1.xsn" name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:Template1:-myXSD-2010-07-21T14-21-13" ?>
  <?mso-application progid="InfoPath.Document" versionProgid="InfoPath.Document.2"?>
  <my:myFields xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2010-07-21T14:21:13" xml:lang="en-us">
    <my:field1>hello</my:field1>
    <my:field2>world</my:field2>
  </my:myFields>
```

What are those top 3 nodes with the question mark  called... and how do I create them in C#?

So far I have this:

```
  XmlDocument xmldoc;
  XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration;

  xmldoc=new XmlDocument();
  xmlDeclaration = xmldoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration, "", "") as XmlDeclaration;
  xmlDeclaration.Encoding = "UTF-8";
  xmldoc.AppendChild(xmlDeclaration);
```

This works fine for the top XML declaration node  , but how do I create the next two?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are called processing instructions. Add 'em using [XmlDocument.CreateProcessingInstruction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.createprocessinginstruction.aspx).

Comment: Note that the first one isn't a processing instruction. It's the XML document declaration. Use [CreateXmlDeclaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.createxmldeclaration.aspx) for this.

Answer (score 7):

Those are called *processing instructions*. You can use the `XmlProcessingInstruction` class to interact with them in an `XmlDocument`.

As with most elements defined within an `XmlDocument`, you cannot instantiate it directly; you must use the appropriate factory method on `XmlDocument` (`CreateProcessingInstruction` in that particular case.)

Comment: Please note what Porges said above: "... the first one isn't a processing instruction. It's the XML document declaration. ..."

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for explaining that these are processing instructions.  Using CreateProcessingInstruction as suggested, here is the solution:

```
  xmlPi = xmldoc.CreateProcessingInstruction("mso-infoPathSolution", "solutionVersion=\"1.0.0.1\" productVersion=\"12.0.0\" PIVersion=\"1.0.0.0\" href=\"file:///C:\\Metastorm\\Sample%20Procedures\\InfoPath%20samples\\Template1.xsn\" name=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:Template1:-myXSD-2010-07-21T14-21-13\"");
  xmldoc.AppendChild(xmlPi);
```

Comment: great, but you should update your question instead of answering your own question.

Comment: Wrong. You are encouraged to answer your own Q and mark it as the solution. Editing Qs leads to confusion and often invalidates previous replies.