# Names of special HTML construct tags

Tags: html, xml, tags, comments, dtd

In HTML, XML, and, partially so, DTDs, there are two kinds of special tag constructs:

- A tag opening with an **exclamation mark** `<!` and closing with the standard `>`, such as `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<!--comment-->`
- A tag opening with a **question mark** `<?` and closing with another question mark `?>`, such as `<?xml version="1.0"?>` and `<?php phpinfo();?>`

My question is, are there ***differing names*** for each of these construct types, or do I have to refer to them as "*the exclamation point tag thingy*" and "*the question mark tag doohicky*" forever?

---

### Answer:

*This answer is largely informed by [kjhughes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/290085/kjhughes)'s answer below.*

Neither [XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/) nor [HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/) explicitly name the `<!` `>` construct in their specifications, with both having different names for each kind of `<!X` `>` structure—`X` representing either `DOCTYPE`, `ELEMENT`, `ENTITY`, `ATTLIST`, `NOTATION`, `--`*, or a [marked section](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/fdp-primer/xml-primer-marked-sections.html) beginning with `[` *.

However, *[SGML](http://www.is-thought.co.uk/book/home.htm)*—the foundation of both HTML and XML—does.

In [SGML](http://www.is-thought.co.uk/book/sgml-4.htm#Fig4-1), a properly filled `<!X` `>` construct is known as an **SGML markup declaration**, with `<!` being the *markup declaration open* delimiter and `>` being the *markup declaration closing* delimiter.

As for the `<?` `?>` construct, both [SGML](http://www.is-thought.co.uk/book/sgml-8.htm#PI) and [HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.3.6) define a similar `<?X` `>` structure known as a **processing instruction** (`X` representing the *processing instruction target*). In this case, `<?` is known as a *processing instruction open* delimiter and is paired with a *processing instruction closing* delimter, which is a solitary `>`.

Neither SGML nor HTML use `?` as part of the processing instruction closing delimiter, essentially making a `?>` closure invalid markup.

However, XML [appears to extend](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-pi) the original SGML specification and uses `?>` to close processing instructions instead of `>`, which is why this form is found in XML documents.

But to add some hair into the soup, a `<?` followed by a case-insensitive `x` `m` `l`  and closed with `?>` is reserved and is ***technically not a processing instruction***. This form is currently only used for [XML declarations](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-prolog-dtd), though it can be argued that XML declarations are just processing instructions for the XML parser itself.

**TL;DR:**

- A full `<!` `>` is an **SGML markup declaration**, but is not explicitly named in HTML** or XML***
- A full `<?` `?>` is a **processing instruction** in XML, but is closed with `>` in SGML and HTML.

---

**Notes:**

*The [HTML 2.0 specification](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_3.html#SEC3.2.5) refers to comments as "***comment declarations***". [Taken together with SGML](http://www.is-thought.co.uk/book/sgml-8.htm#MS), this means that the name of every valid `<!X` `>` form ends in the word "***declaration***".

**The wording of the [HTML 4 recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.4) *does* imply that comments are still a substructure of markup declarations, but it does not refer to comments as "comment declarations" like HTML 2.0.

***XML [*does name*](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-markupdecl) markup declarations; however, the definition does not cover comments or marked sections, which are their own categories in XML.

---

Comment: This question may be helpful for the first one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16321081/what-does-exclamation-point-stand-for-in-html-in-constructs-like-doctype-and-com. And this other for the second part: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335067/in-xml-what-are-the-nodes-with-question-marks-called-and-how-do-i-add-them-in

Comment: Thanks! So, if I understand correctly, the first is called a "_markup declaration_" tag, and the second a "_processing instruction_" tag? Are these formal, codified names, or just community jargon? In other words, what do the core SGML/XML developers call them?

Comment: To be honest, I just used them without giving too much thought to how they were called. In the particular case of PHP, I called it "open tag", but I don't know if that's the technical name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consult the [*W3C Extensible Markup Language (XML) Recommendation*](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/) for modern markup terminology:

- None of those constructs can properly be called *tags*.  A [***tag***](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags) delimits an [***element***](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags) and is one of a start tag (`<div>`), end tag (`</div>`), or an empty tag (`<div/>`).  See also
  [What is the correct terminology of XML's elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33159531/290085)
- `<?xml version="1.0" ... ?>` is an [***XML declaration***](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-XMLDecl).  Note that
  [only one XML declaration is permitted in well-formed XML, and it
  must be at the top if anywhere.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20251895/290085)
- `<?PITarget ... ?>` is a [***processing instruction***](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-pi), provided that
  *PITarget* does not equal xml (in a case-insensitive manner).
- `<!DOCTYPE html ...>` is a [***document type definition***](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-doctype).
- `<!ELEMENT ... >` is a [***element declaration***](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-elementdecl), or generally, [***markup declaration***](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-markupdecl).
- `<!-- comment -->` is a ***[comment](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-comments)***.

The XML Recommendation doesn't specifically label `<!` or `<?`, but it'd be fair to use SGML terminology for those:

- `<!` is a *markup declaration open delimiter* to be matched by a *markup declaration close delimiter*, `>`.
- `<?` is a *processing instruction open delimiter* to be matched by a *processing instruction close delimiter*, `?>` (although in SGML the PI close delimiter was `>`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I suppose I just always assumed they had more general names. The main thing that got me to ask the question was the HTML 4.01 DTD, where comments appear inside declarations. For example, <!ELEMENT panda --this is a comment-- (panda-child*)> appears to be acceptable in a DTD and is probably so in HTML/SGML/XML files as well. And, indeed, according to the SGML specification, the comment actually begins and ends with the "--" marker, not with the "<!--" and "-->" markers. Therefore, I take it that there actually are more technical names, at least for <!> type constructs.

Comment: `<!` is a *markup declaration open delimiter* to be matched by a *markup declaration closing delimiter*, `>`, but the XML spec doesn't explicitly call them out anymore -- they're tied-in with associated literals such as `<!ELEMENT` in the the **elementdecl** production.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! A quick note on my previous comment: an SGML comment must be between two "--" markers within a <!> construct, but the markers do not have to be at the beginning or end of the construct. This is why using double hyphens in a comment can throw errors in Firefox.

Comment: Also, seeing that the open and close markers are called _**markup declaration** open/close delimiters_, this would imply that the entire construct is called a _markup declaration_, though it may not be explicitly stated. The only part of the question that now remains is what the explicit/implicit term or the <??> construct is.

Comment: Similarly, `<?` is a *processing instruction open delimiter* to be matched by a *processing instruction closing delimiter*, `?>`.

Comment: Well, that seems to settle it. If you include these observations in your answer and no one else can answer the question for several days, I'll mark your answer as the accepted one. :D

Answer (score 0):

*This answer is largely informed by [kjhughes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/290085/kjhughes)'s answer above.*

Neither [XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/) nor [HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/) explicitly name the `<!` `>` construct in their specifications, with both having different names for each kind of `<!X` `>` structure—`X` representing either `DOCTYPE`, `ELEMENT`, `ENTITY`, `ATTLIST`, `NOTATION`, `--`*, or a [marked section](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/fdp-primer/xml-primer-marked-sections.html) beginning with `[` *.

However, *[SGML](http://www.is-thought.co.uk/book/home.htm)*—the foundation of both HTML and XML—does.

In [SGML](http://www.is-thought.co.uk/book/sgml-4.htm#Fig4-1), a properly filled `<!X` `>` construct is known as an **SGML markup declaration**, with `<!` being the *markup declaration open* delimiter and `>` being the *markup declaration closing* delimiter.

As for the `<?` `?>` construct, both [SGML](http://www.is-thought.co.uk/book/sgml-8.htm#PI) and [HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.3.6) define a similar `<?X` `>` structure known as a **processing instruction** (`X` representing the *processing instruction target*). In this case, `<?` is known as a *processing instruction open* delimiter and is paired with a *processing instruction closing* delimter, which is a solitary `>`.

Neither SGML nor HTML use `?` as part of the processing instruction closing delimiter, essentially making a `?>` closure invalid markup.

However, XML [appears to extend](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-pi) the original SGML specification and uses `?>` to close processing instructions instead of `>`, which is why this form is found in XML documents.

But to add some hair into the soup, a `<?` followed by a case-insensitive `x` `m` `l`  and closed with `?>` is reserved and is ***technically not a processing instruction***. This form is currently only used for [XML declarations](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-prolog-dtd), though it can be argued that XML declarations are just processing instructions for the XML parser itself.

**TL;DR:**

- A full `<!` `>` is an **SGML markup declaration**, but is not explicitly named in HTML** or XML***
- A full `<?` `?>` is a **processing instruction** in XML, but is closed with `>` in SGML and HTML.

---

**Notes:**

*The [HTML 2.0 specification](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_3.html#SEC3.2.5) refers to comments as "comment declarations". [Taken together with SGML](http://www.is-thought.co.uk/book/sgml-8.htm#MS), this means that the name of every valid `<!X` `>` form ends in the word "***declaration***".

**The wording of the [HTML 4 recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.4) *does* imply that comments are still a substructure of markup declarations, but it does not refer to comments as "comment declarations" like HTML 2.0.

***XML [*does name*](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-markupdecl) markup declarations; however, the definition does not cover comments or marked sections, which are their own categories in XML.

---

Answer (score -2):

Each tag has a name:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> = doctype
<!-- = comment
<?php = php tag
<?xml = xml tag
```

Comment: While I appreciate the answer, these names are assigned on a per-tag basis. What I am looking for is the _overall_ name for each tag type. The reason for this is that, with regard for the doctype declaration, the following is also theoretically valid markup, at least for DTDs: <!DOCTYPE --this is a comment-- html>. As you can see, comments can be enclosed anywhere in a <!> type tag. This should also be valid: <!--this is a comment-- DOCTYPE html>

Comment: **Backtrack**: In checking my above code in HTML and DTD validators, it seems that comments inside DOCTYPE or other DTD declarations are technically invalid, although the W3C HTML 4.01 DTD liberally uses comments inside declarations flanked with double hyphens. It seems to reason, therefore, that comments being inside declarations rather than being the declarations themselves was the original intent.